# Please identify, Lago bike from Germany

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

help me to identify what kind of bicycle frame it is and its cost, if it is valuable, I will be grateful for any information.  (Click images for larger view.)

[image: Badge on the headset]
[image: Label reading "Super Sport"]
[image: Front of the bike with "Lago" on the down tube]
[image: Label reading "Marken Ausfuhrung"]
[image: Rear triangle]
[image: Seatpost clamp]
[image: Detail of seat post]
[image: Close-up of "Liebigt" logo with block gold bird on seat post]
[image: Close-up of decal at top of down tube]

Comment: is that "LLH" in the middle of the globe? I can't tell due to the glare. It looks like there are more labels on the frame. More pictures help us identify your frame. All labels and any distinctive features of the frame.

Comment: Thanks, I do more photos and edited my post

Comment: The third image says "Marken Ausführung", which is German. So it could be Austrian, Swiss or German brand.

Comment: It has mounting brackets for a full chain guard. It might have been a three speed originally, or maybe a five speed. I can read any of the decals on the seat tube.

Comment: Very interesting, tomorrow I will add more photos from the seat tube, maybe they will be able to tell exactly what kind of rarity it is.  thank

Comment: Add more photos, please help identify

Comment: @marco are those not Italian flag colours on the fork, but rotated?  Or in that orientation, wikipedia suggests "Flag of North Rhine-Westphalia"  which would be German.   Nice bike.

Comment: It's your call but I hope you don't repaint it. The original paint and decals are wonderful and it would be sad to sand them away. I've never seen diamond cut outs on head tube lugs before.

Comment: Does anyone know what the bracket on the left seat stay is?

Comment: That's a great set of photos so far. Are there any numbers stamped into the bottom bracket, either underneath or on top? If so, can you add photos of those?

Comment: Thank you for your keen interest in my question about this frame, the frame is still en route to me in the mail.  Therefore, I will not be able to take more photos, only in a week.  As I get it in my hands, I will definitely look for numbers or some symbols.  At the moment, quite a few innovations have been found thanks to you.  And fortunately, I do not plan to repaint my native paint, as I plan to keep this copy in this form.

Answer (score 2):

The last image says

> Moped-Fahrrad (Moped Bike)
> Mähmaschinen (Lawnmowers)
> OTTO D... (A name obv.)
> Reperatur...Werkstatt. (Repairshop prob.)
> Friedrichs.....en? (Riedrichshafen? Reflection in the way)

That would be a sticker from a repair / service shop for mopeds, bikes and lawnmowers

The second to last should be the brand, as there is another bike from "Liebigt" for sale here: http://www.dealmywheel.de/neue-gebrauchte-fahrraeder/muenchen/741027/frisch-restauriertes-sammlerstueck.php

I can find a few second-hand Liebigt frames on ebay and other German thrift sites, but I'm unable to find any wikipedia article or related information on that name, so other then confirming, that "Liebigt" is indeed the vendor, I can't provide any information on the model other then it should be from around the 1970s or earlier.

Comment: Nice answer. I want to add a couple of details (I speak some german, so it helped).
All that follows is translated from some posts in a German forum https://www.altesrad.net/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9734&p=77622&hilit=liebigt#p77622

The company Franz Liebigt was founded in 1935 in Dessau, after the war was moved to Haag/Obb.

There are many brands coming from the Franz Liebigt factory:
Ascona, Cortina, Elfa, FLH, Franz ?, Lago, Nostra, Palma, Slalom, Sperber

*-----------
You may ask them:
https://historische-fahrraeder.de/verein-vorstand/
for more informations.

Comment: I'm a native German - so if you need help translating anything else from there - just shoot. Happy to help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=liebigt+fahrrad&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01trd0fungyGH58mhYsUKbPZMfB9g%3A1616604925154&ei=_W5bYJrlCKfa5gLp8bPQDw&oq=liebigt+fahrrad&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6525.10436.0.10798.8.8.0.0.0.0.131.807.4j4.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.359...33i299k1j33i10k1.0.PLLXGvdDk1o

Answer (score 2):

The logo on the headtube is hard to read, but it looks like it has the letters FLH, which is another sign of it being a bicycle coming from the company (F)ranz (L)iebigt, based in (H)aag. ( [see similar logo in Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/schutzblechfiguren/7790654908) )

The factory was founded in Dessau in 1935 and it moved after the second world war from
Dessau to Haag, therefore the bicycle cannot be older than 1945.

The factory produced bicycle with different brands (Ascona, Cortina, Elfa, FLH, Franz Liebigt, **Lago**, Nostra, Palma, Slalom, Sperber, according to info from this [forum](https://www.altesrad.net/), which is accessible only after registration).

The factory was dissolved in 1992 ([according to this site](https://www.northdata.de/Franz+Liebigt+Gro%C3%9Fhandelshaus+GmbH,+Haag/Amtsgericht+Traunstein+HRB+2139)), so it cannot be newer than 1992 (well, not that you needed proof of that).

Comment: Thanks, this is real good information for me.